# Are Alloy Compositions Given in Weight Percent or Atom Percent

Tags: metal, notation, metallurgy, alloy

Often times I see alloys described like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockalloy),

> Lockalloy is an alloy that consists of 62% beryllium and 38% aluminum

Are the precentages mentioned here in weight percent or atom percent?  Is there a standard somewhere that governs this notation?  I don't see this mentioned anywhere in the literature, how does everyone know when people are talking about weight or atom percentages?

Comment: Sometimes they will be nice and indicate ’wt.%’ or ‘at.%”, otherwise you have to look deeper at the document to see, or another source to compare. Metallurgy often uses weight percent, materials science atomic percent.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiGgbTP2f3sAhWaKs0KHWs5Ag0QFjACegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmaterion.com%2F-%2Fmedia%2Ffiles%2Fberyllium%2Falbemet-materials%2Fmaab-006developmentofaluminumberylliumforstructuralapplications.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2njAxQKRimUzRiDZJelTYS would indicate it is by weight : "Aluminum-beryllium (AlBeMet® AM162) is a powder metallurgy composite of Beryllium 62% by weight and 1100 series pure aluminum, 38% by weight."

Comment: Engineers think weight per-cent . I can hardly remember  seeing atomic % , no doubt in some research paper.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it is left unspecified, it is weight percent. I don't know of an official standard, but it is a very common tradition.